# can't convert expression to float error in integration

Tags: numpy, sympy, ode

I have a third-order ODE with time-varying coefficients of the form

**y''' + A1(t)y'' + A2(t)y' + A3(t)y = 0**

Where A1, A2, and A3 contain differentiation of a different function
R(t) = a - b* atan (c*t-d)

I have written the code below but I keep getting "can't convert expression to float error" error.
My python skill is not strong.

I would appreciate if I could get an advice on how to approach this.

Thanks

```
#import math
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.integrate import odeint
from sympy import *
#from math import *
def du_dt(y,x):
    return [ y[1], y[2], (- A1*y[2] - A2*y[1] + A3*y[0]) ] 

V = 2.5e3
Ra = 7.5e3
C1 = 3.3e-6
RL = 1.10
L = 3.32e-6
C2 = 3.16e-12
Rd = 0.5 
w1 = 1/(C1*L)
T1 = Ra*C1
C23 = C1*C2/(C1+C2)
w2 = 1/(L*C23)
R5 = 0.015 - 0.006*atan(x-5) 
Tm = L/(RL+R5)
A1 = 1/Tm + 1/T1    
A2 = (1/Tm).diff(x)+w2+(1/L)*R5.diff(x)+1/(T1*Tm) 
A3 = (1/L)*R5.diff(x,2)+(1/(L*T1))*R5.diff(x)+(w2-w1)/T1 

t = np.linspace(0,0.2,1000) # time range
y0 = [3.0425e10,0,0] # initial values
y = odeint(du_dt, y0, t)

#  TypeError: can't convert expression to float
```

Comment: don't use sympy expressions in scipy functions - especially if you are a python novice!

Comment: Your initialization is incomplete.  What is `x`?  `np`?  Show some intermediate results.  For example what is `du_dt(y0,0)`?  Explain why you think this will work in `odeint`?

Comment: Don't use `from sympy import *` if you expect to mix sympy with anything else like numpy.

Comment: Thanks for the comments, @hpaulj. 
Explain why you think this will work in odeint? I used it for a similar ODE problem but with constants coefficients and got same results as MATLAB's. 

What is x? I have a typo here, x = np.linspace(0,0.2,1000)
y = odeint(du_dt, y0, x)

Comment: But what about the `x` in the `R5`, `A2` etc expressions.  I'm guessing your `atan` is the sympy one, and those coefficients are sympy expressions.  That means that `du_dt` returns a list of sympy expressions.  But `odeint` works with a float dtype array.  Look at the the error - sympy says it can't return a float value.  (In retrospect I should have complained about the missing traceback and left it at that!).

Comment: @hpaulj, yes, your guess is correct.  
My interpretation of x in A2 and A3 is differentiating a symbolic function R5 (similar to the `syms` in MATLAB).
Do you suggest that I declare x as a symbol? something like `x = sp.Symbol('x')` then use `sp.integrate` instead of `odeint'  working only with sympy?
I didn't know that I have to include the traceback. I'm sorry about that.